# Building an inverted index

Tags: kotlin

I am having a hard time building an inverted index for the following assignment

Suppose you have the following array or list of lines (I am importing them from a file!):

```
0: Katie Jacobs
1: Erick Harrington harrington@gmail.com
2: Myrtle Medina
3: Erick Burgess
```

For these lines, the inverted index will look like this:

```
Katie -> [0]
Jacobs -> [0]
Erick -> [1, 3]
Harrington -> [1]
harrington@gmail.com -> [1]
Myrtle -> [2]
Medina -> [2]
Burgess -> [3]
```

The order of pairs is not important. If you are searching for Erick, you can immediately get the target fields using this mapping.

Output example later on:

```
Enter a name or email to search all suitable people.
> ERICK
2 persons found:
Erick Harrington harrington@gmail.com
Erick Burgess
```

I played around with the following code but I am not quite sure how to map the word to the corresponding line number so I can search for it later or if I even am going in the right direction.

```
val invertedIndex = mutableMapOf<List<String>, Int>()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    if (args[0] == "--data") {
        File(args[1]).forEachLine { line ->
            for (word in line.split(" ")) {
To Do???
            }
        }
    }
    else println("Invalid input")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val map = File("input.txt").useLines { lines ->
    lines.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
        .flatMapIndexed { index, value ->
            value.splitToSequence(" ")
                .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
                .map { index to it }
        }
        .groupBy({ (_, name) -> name }, { (index, _) -> index })
}
println(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out the basic steps your loop needs to take. Don't worry about the code yet, can you explain it in English? What do you need to do for each line? What data do you need to put into that map, and where do you get it from? How do you store it, what checks do you need to do? Work out what you need to do, step by step.

Also look at your `invertedIndex` map, are you sure that signature's right? Is it describing the way the data you're storing is structured? Look at your example of an index, what does each line look like?

I'm not doing your homework for you but I can give you some hints! Working out how to solve these problems is what coding actually is though, the writing code part is sort of secondary